# How to get portion of div ID using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page I have a div which looks like this: `<div id="entry-7265">...</div>`

Using either jQuery or JavaScript, how can I get the digit portion of the div's ID? e.g. I don't need the `entry-` bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a way of referencing it first...

Comment: Is the id always "entry-xxxxx", and separated by hyphen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the ID in question seems to be dynamic, I suggest you use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById` like in PellePenna's answer.

```
var id = querySelectorAll("[id*='entry-']");
var someArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<id.length; i++) {
    someArray.push(parseInt(id[i].split("-")[1]),10);
}
```

That will give you an array of integers, instead of string numbers.

Answer (score 0):

How about: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NU2XH/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="entry" data-id="7265">...</div>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".entry").click(function () {
        var data = $(this).data("id");
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

---

Alternative for a list of items: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NU2XH/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="entry" data-id="7265">...</div>
<div class="entry" data-id="7266">...</div>
<div class="entry" data-id="7267">...</div>
<div class="entry" data-id="7268">...</div>

<div id="list"></div>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".entry").each(function (index, element) {
        var data = $(element).data("id");
        $("#list").text($("#list").text() + " " + data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var reg = /^\d+$/; 
    var divId = "entry-7265";
    var num = reg.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about;

```
$("[id^=entry-]").each(function() {
    if (/entry-\d{4}/.test(this.id))
        alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
$("[id^='entry-']").each(function(){
    //List of all ids starting with entry
    $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
})
```